# what is more efficient in performance of hbase,multiple tables of same structure or a single table containing large set of data?

Tags: hadoop, namespaces, hbase

I had earlier created a project of storing daily data of particular entity in RDMS by creating a single table for each day and than storing data of that day in this table.

But now i want to shift my database from RDMS to HBase. So my question is whether I should create a single table and store data of all days in that table or I should use my earlier concept of creating a individual table for each day.I want to compare both cases on basis of performance of hbase.

Sorry if that question seems foolish to you.Thank you

Comment: think about structure of your table. If the row is timestamp, it will cause hot regions problem.

Comment: If you rowkey is well designed,and adresses issue like what Natalia mentioned,then following the design of your RDBMS system defeats the whole purpose of HBase.

Comment: Ok,so you want to say that i should enter my whole data into a single table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned there are 2 options

---

> Option 1: Single table of all days data
>   Option 2: multiple tables

---

I would prefer Namespaces (introduced in version 0.96 is a very important feature) with option 2 if you have huge data for single day. This will support multi tenancy requirements also...

See [Hbase Book](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_namespace)

> - A namespace is a logical grouping of tables analogous to a database in relation database systems. This abstraction lays the groundwork for
>     upcoming multi-tenancy related features: Quota Management (HBASE-8410)
> - Restrict the amount of resources (ie regions, tables) a namespace can consume.
> - Namespace Security Administration (HBASE-9206) - Provide another level of security administration for tenants.
> - Region server groups (HBASE-6721) - A namespace/table can be pinned onto a subset of - RegionServers thus guaranteeing a course level of
>     isolation.
>
> below are commands w.r.t. namespaces
>
> ```
> alter_namespace, create_namespace, describe_namespace, 
> drop_namespace, list_namespace, list_namespace_tables
> ```

***Advantage :***

- Even if you use column filters, since its less data(per day data), data retrieval will be fast for full table scan compared to single table approach(full scan on big table is costly)
- If you want authentication and authorization on a specific table then it could also be achived.

***Limitation*** : you will end up with multiple scripts to manage tables rather single script(option 1)

#### Note : In any afore mentioned options above,your rowkey design is very imp for better performance &  prevent hotspoting.

For more details look at [hbase-series](http://www.bigsynapse.com/hbase-series)

Comment: Thank you so much,i got my exact answer.